# Kafka consumer stuck (in fact pauses and resumes) at iterator.hasNext() even though there are plenty of messages to consume in the topic

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

I am working on a distributed solution with 2 consumers running on 2 different servers under the same consumer group and consuming from a 3-machine Kafka topic with 2 partitions and replication factor 3. Inside my consumer class (which is a `Callable`), the key part looks like below:

```
@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
    try {            
        while (it.hasNext()){
            byte[] message = it.next().message();
            // other code here
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    log.error("Shutting down Thread: " + streamNumber + ", kafka consumer offline!!!");
}
```

My consumer class also spawns 16 other threads to do stuffs with the consumed messages. When I start both my consumers on 2 different servers, first few minutes each of them seem to seamlessly consume messages from the Kafka topic (one partition each). However, after a certain time, each consumer seem to be stuck at the `while (it.hasNext())` statement, even though there are thousands of messages left to be consumed in each partition. Below is the screenshot that shows the status of the Kafka consumer offsets at that point.

[image: Kafka Consumer Offset Status]

As you can see, the consumers are far behind the number of messages available in the topic. From my logs, it looks like while this consuming thread is paused, other threads are running fine and doing their jobs. From a longer run, interestingly I have also noticed that the consuming thread is kind of pausing and resuming after some time. However, each time it pauses, the number of messages consumed next time also decraeses ridiculously. For example, after I first started both consumers, each seemed to seamlessly consume some 15,000 messages until getting stuck at the stream iterator, then paused for like 20 - 25 minutes and consumed like 5,000 more, then again paused for like 30 minutes and consumed like a 100 more and this goes on. If I stop the consumer processes and restart, the whole cycle seem to repeat.

These are the consumer configs I am using:

```
group.id=ct_job_backfill     
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=1000
zookeeper.sync.time.ms=200
auto.commit.enable=true
auto.offset.reset=smallest
rebalance.max.retries=20
rebalance.backoff.ms=2000
topic.name=contentTaskProd
```

The consumer servers are each 32-thread 64 GB machines running on Linux.

Any idea what might be causing this? Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need additional information or if anything is unclear.

> **UPDATE**: I have tried increasing the number of partitions from 2 to 32, and inside each of my consumer server spawning 16 consumers threads each consuming from a partition. However, that doesn't seem to change the behaviour. I notice the same pause and resume cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have came across exactly the same issue. While browsing for the resolution I came across issue already reported with kafka at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2978.

Looks like they have resolved in 0.9.0.1 version. I am gonna try and update the library with this version. Will update if I am able to resolve this issue with new jar. In the meantime you can try the same.
~Cheers